# Getting an "Identifier not found" error on compiling a class

Tags: c++, visual-c++

[Link to pastebin](http://pastebin.com/kBEcuZRQ)

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. It's simply not letting me access the getTypeEffectiveness function - almost like I've either misspelled it or I haven't written it yet. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at line 21. You are defining the prototype as "double getEffectiveness (TYPING, TYPING);"

It should be "double getTypeEffectiveness (TYPING, TYPING);"

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the function before you use it, like this:

```
double getTypeEffectiveness(TYPING attack, TYPING defend);
```

(or just move the definition above the place you use it).

Answer (score 0):

getTypeEffectiveness vs getEffectiveness

Comment: Admittedly, this is terse, but it is the solution. By reading it, the OP will understand.